# CPU load and hyperthreading

Tags: linux, cpu, hyperthreading

If I have two physical cores and hyperthreading enabled, is the CPU load computed against two cores or fours?

In other words, is complete load indicated by `2.0` or `4.0`?

Comment: Its actually becomes 4.0

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. In fact, the answer to my question isn't in the referenced question.